# How do I get file path for image in a hidden folder?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make an easter egg where an image displays when a user clicks a button with certain text input. I put the image in a hidden folder, but it is not displaying. This is the code:

HTML

```
<input type="textbox" id="text1">
<input type="button" value="Generate Entry" onclick="submitButtonClicked();secretFunction()">
```

JS

```
function secretFunction(){
    let secretCode = document.getElementById("text1").value;
    if (secretCode == "Secret" || secretCode == "secret"){
            var win2 = window.open("", "Title", "toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=780,height=650,top="+(screen.height-400)+",left="+(screen.width-840));
            win2.document.body.innerHTML = "<img src='/img/secretImage.png'>" + "<br><h1>Congratulations!</h1>"
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

hidden folders normally are preceded by a . so a hidden folder might be images/.hidden/image.jpg.  try changing the `<img src=''>` line 
most likely you have not put a valid path to the image`

Comment: I tried "<img src='/.img/secretImage.png'>" but that did not work

Comment: @rkafds dots for a relative path should be before the forward slash, not after (so instead try `<img src="../img/secretImage.png">`)

Comment: @rkafds try `<img src=".img/secretImage.png">` it works on my computer but it may be different on another operating system i use Linux